# Building the Spokes Effect with Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Which API functions would you use to build a map that has a spoke effect like this one when you click on a county?

http://www.forbes.com/special-report/2011/migration.html

Using TileMIll and/or Mapbox

Answer (score 0):

You would, given data in GeoJSON, add it to a GeoJSON layer. When someone clicks, find all related polygons, compute their centroids, create lines from the clicked polygon to those centroids. Add those to the map as a temporary layer. See the [Leaflet reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) for the specific functions you would need to use.